# reorganize a dataframe in python by copying value from specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has three columns per student. It looks like this:

```
old_df =    
Student s1  s2  s3  code
    A   a1  a2  a3  aaa
    B   b1  b2  b3  bbb
    C   c1  c2  nan ccc
    D   d1  nan nan ddd
```

[df_old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ8f7.jpg)

I need to merge three columns s1,s2,s3 to just one column, like this:
[df_new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps4li.png)

```
new_df = 
Student s   code
  A    a1   aaa
  A    a2   aaa
  A    a3   aaa
  B    b1   bbb
  B    b2   bbb
  B    b3   bbb
  C    c1   ccc
  C    c2   ccc
  C    nan  ccc
  D   d1    ddd
  D  nan    ddd
  D  nan    ddd
```

I have tried so far iterrows() to create a list but its not going anywhere. I think I am totally missing tools that are better suitable for this kind of restructuring of dataframe

```
t1=[] 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    t1.append(row['Student'])
    t1.append(row['s1'])
    t1.append(row['code'])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not a good way to just post a picture of data. Instead, providing raw text sample data will more better.

Comment: Just added the raw data

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack()` will help.

```py
df.set_index(['Student', 'code']).stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
```